# User/Address association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, location, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I'm working on my first Rails project and I'm trying create a proper User/Address (or rather User/Location) association. I thought my problem was common and that others had done what I'm trying successfully and that it would be easy to find an answer but it wasn't the case. There are many different questions with extremely different answers and I couldn't figure out how to do things in my case. Here's my scenario:

The location can be a country, State/Region or City, not more specific than that (I'm using Google Places Library's autocomplete feature). So to avoid a lot of duplicate information in the `users` table every time one or more users live in the same city (country, state, city, latitude, longitude etc), I figured I should have a `locations` table. Even worse, the user should have a "home_location" and "current_location". Now the associations:

**has_one**

At first I thought: "Well, a user has an address/location, so I should probably use the `has_one` association. But it turns out that if I use `user has_one location`, the location table will be the one pointing to the user's table, which is not what I want, since many users should be able to reference the same location.

**belongs_to/has_many**

"OK, then I'll use the belongs_to/has_many association" I thought. Seemed pretty neat at first. Seemed to make a lot of sense. I'm using the nested forms gem, which works pretty well for everything else I've done so far, and the nested form for locations loaded and the information was sent correctly. The location was created and added to the database successfully, but there was one problem: The user.location wasn't saved. Trying to figure out why, I realize there's something very weird about this whole thing. Rails is not treating this design structure the way I need (the way I feel is more intuitive). Indeed, usually this association is used for "user/microposts" (like in [Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/)) and this kind of thing. But in my case the idea is different. We humans understand that, but Rails doesn't seem to. I want a user to be able to say where he lives in his "edit profile" page. But  From what I've been reading it seems like rails is expecting the *LOCATION'S* edit page to have a nested form for users. Like it's expecting me to create a user like this:

```
@location.user.create(:email=>"john@example.com")
```

While what I need is to create a location like this:

```
@user.location.create(:city=>"Rio de Janeiro", etc)
```

OK. Maybe what I want is too specific and Rail's standard association won't work. After all this code above would create duplicate cities, so I'd need something like:

`@user.location.find_or_create(:city=>"Rio de Janeiro")` (Does this even exist for associated objects?)

Here's the code for this attempt that saved the location successfully but didn't create the association:

**model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ... :home_location, :home_location_attributes,
                  :current_location, :current_location_attributes, etc


  belongs_to :home_location, :class_name => 'Location'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :home_location

  belongs_to :current_location, :class_name => 'Location'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :current_location

  ...
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :google_id, :latitude, :longitude,
                  :administrative_area_level_1, :administrative_area_level_2,
                  :city, :neighborhood, :country, :country_id

  belongs_to :country

  has_many :users
end
```

**schema**

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    ...
    t.integer  "home_location"
    t.integer  "current_location"
    t.text     "about_me"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         :null => false
    ...
  end

  create_table "locations", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "google_id",                   :null => false
    t.string   "latitude",                    :null => false
    t.string   "longitude",                   :null => false
    t.integer  "country_id",                  :null => false
    t.string   "administrative_area_level_1"
    t.string   "administrative_area_level_2"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "neighborhood"
    t.datetime "created_at",                  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  :null => false
  end
```

But then it seemed what I wanted was too particular so I gave everything up and tried to simply add a `form_for @location`. Then I could check in the user controller if the record already existed and save it in the user's home_location attribute. So I removed the following lines from the user model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :home_location
accepts_nested_attributes_for :current_location
```

And replaced the `f.fields_for` in the edit_profile view with `form_for @location`.

Then in the controller I added some code to deal with the location:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user,  only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :signed_out_user, only: [:new, :create]
  before_filter :correct_user,    only: [:edit, :update]

  ...
  def edit
    if @user.speaks.length == 0
      @user.speaks.new
    end
    if @user.wants_to_learn.length == 0
      @user.wants_to_learn.new
    end
    if @user.home_location.blank?
      @user.home_location = Location.new
    end
  end

  def update
    logger.debug params

    ...

    @home_location = nil

    params[:home_location][:country_id] = params[:home_location].delete(:country)

    unless params[:home_location][:country_id].blank?
      params[:home_location][:country_id] = Country.find_by_iso_3166_code(params[:home_location][:country_id]).id

      #@home_location = Location.where(params[:home_location])
      #The line above describe the behavior I actually want,
      #but for testing purposes I simplified as below:
      @home_location = Location.find(2) #There is a Location with id=2 in the DB

      if @home_location.nil?
        @home_location = Location.new(params[:home_location])
        if !@home_location.save then @home_location = nil end
      end
    end

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      @user.home_location = @home_location
      @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      #render :action => :edit
      redirect_to :action => :edit
    else
      render :action => :edit
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

But still it doesn't save the association. In fact even in the console, no matter what I do, the user's home_location attribute never gets saved to the database.

Does anybody have any idea of what may be happening??

Why is the association not being saved? What's is the most correct way of doing this in Rails?

I'm sorry about the length of the question. Hope somebody reads it. I'd be very grateful!

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

Following RobHeaton's tip, I added a custom setter in my User model:

```
  def home_location= location #params[:user][:home_location]
   locations = Location.where(location)
   @home_location = locations.first.id unless locations.empty?
  end
```

After fixing some issues that popped up, it started working! The data was finally saved to the database. I still have no idea why it didn't work in the controller though. Does any body have any guess? I'm wondering if the mistake wasn't actually somewhere else and I ended up fixing it without noticing just because the code was better organized in the model.

Still, the problem is not completely solved. Although the value is saved to the database, I can't access the associated model in the standard Rails way.

```
1.9.3p362 :001 > ariel = User.first
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, first_name: "Ariel", last_name: "Pontes", username: nil, email: "pontes@ariel.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$Ue8dh/nRh9kL9lUd8JjQU.okD6TtE
i4H1tphmRoNIQ15...", remember_token: "kadybXrh1g0X-BE_HxhA4w", date_of_birth: nil, gender: nil, interested_in: 0, relationship_status: nil, home_location: 3, curr
ent_location: nil, about_me: "", created_at: "2013-05-07 14:28:05", updated_at: "2013-05-09 20:10:41", home_details: nil, current_details: nil> 
1.9.3p362 :002 > ariel.home_location
 => nil
```

The weird thing is that not only isn't Rails able to return the associated object, it won't even return the integer id stored in the object! How does that make any sense? I was hoping for a Location object and, worst case scenario, expecting a 3 in return. But instead I get nil.

I tried to write a custom getter anyway:

```
  def home_location
    if @home_location.blank? then return nil end
    Location.find(@home_location)
  end
```

But of course it doesn't work. Any more ideas??

Comment: You want to change your column names for the user locations to be `home_location_id` and `current_location_id` to work with the "belongs_to" relationships you've set up.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't really work =/ These really are the names of the columns in the database. The default "_id" probably wasn't added because I gave them custom names, since there were 2 foreign keys pointing to the same table.

Comment: I don't know what you mean about it not working. It's a Rails convention to use a `:custom_name_id` foreign key in your database and an association `belongs_to :custom_name, class_name: 'Location'` in your model. By using the same name for both the column and the belongs_to association, you're going against the Rails convention which typically causes problems unless you use a workaround.

Comment: Oh, so you meant actually changing the database column names! Of course, I had the model's attributes in mind even though you said "column". I had only changed the models, then of course it wasn't enough. I was confused but now I think I understand the convention. I changed the database column names and it finally works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

Thanks to RobHeaton for enlightening me about good practices and to rossta for explaining Rails' conventions.

Here's the configuration I have now:

**model**

```
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, ...,
                :home_location, :home_location_id, :home_location_attributes,
                :current_location, :current_location_id, :current_location_attributes, ...

...

belongs_to :home_location, :class_name => 'Location'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :home_location

belongs_to :current_location, :class_name => 'Location'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :current_location
```

**schema**

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  ...
  t.integer  "home_location_id"
  t.integer  "current_location_id"
  ...
end
```

My controller is untouched. Actually even cleaner than before, no more messing around with params.

As for the custom setters, they weren't even necessary for the purposes I described in the question after all. But it helped me organize my code and make it easier to spot mistakes. I'm using them now for other things I had to fix along the way and to keep my controller clean.

It seems Rails does understand both "types" of belongs_to/has_many associations after all! It's funny that didn't find the distinction being made explicitly anywhere though. Ended up assuming Rails couldn't do it when in fact all I had to do was correct some names to respect the conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def location= city_name
    write_attribute :location, Location.find_by_city_name(city_name)
  end

end
```

should do it. You can define `state=`, `city=` and so on and in each case just do the find by the appropriate column. As a general principle you want to get as much of this logic out of your controllers as possible. As soon as you are writing 10+ lines of code to process some incoming params you want to consider whether you can do this in the model.

Comment: Now I get `undefined method 'to_i' for #<Location:0x007fc2d9f2ff28>` in this line:

`@user.home_location = Location.new`

Comment: Besides, I can't save a new location only with a city name. There are different locations with the same city name (Springfield AR x Springfield CA, or even different neighborhoods in the same city) so I use 5 columns:

country
administrative_area_level_1
administrative_area_level_2
city
neighborhood

to determine whether a location already exists or not. Can I send a hash full of parameters to this assignment method instead of only city_name?

Comment: In principle yes, although the best way to do it will depend on a few things. What data do you get sent to you from your form?

Comment: I get the error when I try to load the edit profile page, no data sent. The line `@user.home_location = Location.new` creates an empty location in case the user doesn't already have one so that an empty form for location gets built. Otherwise there'd be no form at all. But now apparently it's an illegal assignment. I removed it and this time it works and there's actually a form anyway, but when I send it I get the same error.

Comment: The relevant (too long to paste everything) data sent: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ZmaU…",
 "user"=>{"speaks_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"language_id"=>"129",
 "level"=>"6",
 "_destroy"=>"false",
 "id"=>"1"}},
 "wants_to_learn_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"language_id"=>"",
 "_destroy"=>"false"}},
 "home_location"=>{"google_id"=>"7789d95...",
 "latitude"=>"-22.90",
 "longitude"=>"-43.20",
 "city"=>"Rio de Janeiro",
 "neighborhood"=>"",
 "administrative_area_level_1"=>"RJ",
 "administrative_area_level_2"=>"",
 "country_id"=>"BR"},
…
 "interested_in"=>0},
 "id"=>"1"}

Comment: Overwriting that assignment method seemed to mess everything up at first but, after fixing all sorts of errors that appeared (don't even remember), it finally works! The database value is finally changing! Thanks a lot for the insight =D There's another problem though: Probably because Rails doesn't seem to understand the association I'm trying to build, `some_user.home_location` returns nil even though there is a valid id stored in the column. I tried to write a custom getter but it didn't work either. It only returns nil. Any idea what I might be missing? Thanks!

Comment: As someone mentioned above, you need to name your columns `home_location_id` etc. `home_location` won't trigger Rails to think "ooh here's an association!"